# slightly adapted HOC in react DRY

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple HOC which injects a react context as a prop in the wrappedcomponent.

```
function withTranslate(WrappedComponent) {
//we forward the ref so it can be used by other 
  return React.forwardRef((props, ref) => ( 
    <TranslatorContext.Consumer>
      {context => (<WrappedComponent {...props} translate={context} ref={ref} />)}
    </TranslatorContext.Consumer>)
  )
}
```

Now I want a secondary HOC which uses the same context, but changes some predefined props using this context. I succeed with following code:

```
export function withTranslatedProps(WrappedComponent,propsToBeTransLated) {
        //propsToBetranslated is array with all props which will be given via keys
        const translateProps=(translate,props)=>{
            const ownProps=Object.assign({},props)
            propsToBeTransLated.forEach(p=>{
                if(ownProps.hasOwnProperty(p)){
                    ownProps[p]=translate(ownProps[p])
                }
            })
            return ownProps
        }
        return React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
            console.log("render contextconsumer")
            return (
                <TranslatorContext.Consumer>
                    {context => (
                        <WrappedComponent {...translateProps(context,props)} ref={ref} />
                    )}
                </TranslatorContext.Consumer>)
        })
    }
```

But I almost exactly use the same HOC as withTranslate. Is there a better option (without repeating myself) to do this?

***edit***
I think i solved it:

```
const _translateProps=(propsToBeTransLated,translate,props)=>{
            const ownProps=Object.assign({},props)
            propsToBeTransLated.forEach(p=>{
                if(ownProps.hasOwnProperty(p)){
                    ownProps[p]=translate(ownProps[p])
                }
            })
            return ownProps
        }
    export function withTranslatedProps(WrappedComponent,propsToBeTransLated) {
        //propsToBetranslated is array with all props which will be given via keys
        let retrieveProps=propsToBeTransLated?_translateProps.bind(null,propsToBeTransLated):(context,props)=>({translate:context,...props})
        return React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
            console.log("render contextconsumer")
            return (
                <TranslatorContext.Consumer>
                    {context => (
                        <WrappedComponent {...retrieveProps(context,props)} ref={ref} />
                    )}
                </TranslatorContext.Consumer>)
        })
    }
```

Anyone with other possibly better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse withTranslate HOC or use the same HOC adding options.

**Reusing withTranslate HOC:**

```
/* function that translate the propsToBeTransLated */
const translateProps = (propsToBeTransLated, translate, props) => 
  propsToBeTransLated.reduce((translatedProps, prop) => {
    if(props.hasOwnProperty(prop))
      translatedProps[prop] = translate(props[prop]);

    return translatedProps;
  }, {});

export function withTranslatedProps(WrappedComponent, propsToBeTransLated = []) {
  // HOC inside HOC
  const addTranslationsToProps = WrappedComponentWithContext =>
    React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
      <WrappedComponentWithContext
        {...props}
        {...translateProps(propsToBeTransLated, props.translate, props)}
        ref={ref}
      />
    )
  );

  // first call withTranslate to add the context
  return addTranslationsToProps(withTranslate(WrappedComponent));
}
```

**Adding options to withTranslate HOC**

```
const translateProps = (propsToBeTransLated, translate, props) =>
  propsToBeTransLated.reduce((translatedProps, prop) => {
    if(props.hasOwnProperty(prop))
      translatedProps[prop] = translate(props[prop]);

    return translatedProps;
  }, {});

export function withTranslate(WrappedComponent, options) {
  const { propsToBeTransLated = [] } = options;
  return React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <TranslatorContext.Consumer>
      {context => (
        <WrappedComponent
          {...props}
          {...translateProps(propsToBeTransLated, context, props)}
          translate={context}
          ref={ref}
        />
      )}
    </TranslatorContext.Consumer>
  ));
}
```

Comment: I like your second solution. The reduce function is also very nice. Thanks